# Portability and length of std::string on Windows vs. Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, portability, stdstring

I'm running into some portability problems with C++11 `std::string` length. On Windows it is `long long unsigned int` but on Linux and Mac it is `long unsigned int`. My understanding is that using `auto` is a standard approach to resolving problems like this, but I'm having some difficulty finding a portable way to expose these attributes via a class interface.

---

The following class compiles and runs without problems on Linux GCC 7.3.0 (and also on MacOS):

```
g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -Werror=conversion stringwrap.cc
./a.out
3
```

---

But on Windows (g++ 8.1.0 MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh-rev0), I get the following compile error:

```
C:\temp\v0.11>g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -Werror=conversion stringwrap.cc
In file included from stringwrap.cc:1:
stringwrap.h: In function 'long unsigned int determineFirstPosition(std::__cxx11::string)':
stringwrap.h:35:20: error: conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'}
to 'long unsigned int' may change value [-Werror=conversion]
     return s.length();
            ~~~~~~~~^~
stringwrap.cc: In member function 'long unsigned int Stringwrap::length() const':
stringwrap.cc:9:23: error: conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'}
to 'long unsigned int' may change value [-Werror=conversion]
     return str_.length();
            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
cc1plus.exe: some warnings being treated as errors
```

---

**stringwrap.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Stringwrap
{
  private:
    std::string str_;

  public:

    Stringwrap(const std::string& str);

    unsigned long int length() const;

    unsigned long int getFirstPosition() const;
};

inline unsigned long int determineFirstPosition(const std::string s)
{
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (s.at(i))
        {
            case ' ':
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return s.length();
}
```

---

**stringwrap.cc**

```
#include "stringwrap.h"

Stringwrap::Stringwrap(const std::string& str) : str_(str)
{
}

unsigned long int Stringwrap::length() const
{
    return str_.length();
}

unsigned long int Stringwrap::getFirstPosition() const
{
    return determineFirstPosition(str_);
}

int main()
{
    Stringwrap sw = *new Stringwrap("   x   ");
    std::cout << sw.getFirstPosition() << std::endl;
}
```

---

I've tried changing all of the `unsigned long int`s to `auto`, and with `-std=c++11` I get the following errors:

```
C:\temp\v0.11>g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -Werror=conversion stringwrap.cc
In file included from stringwrap.cc:1:
stringwrap.h:13:19: error: 'length' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
     auto length() const;
                   ^~~~~
stringwrap.h:13:19: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
stringwrap.h:15:29: error: 'getFirstPosition' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
     auto getFirstPosition() const;
                             ^~~~~
stringwrap.h:15:29: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
stringwrap.h:18:55: error: 'determineFirstPosition' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
 inline auto determineFirstPosition(const std::string s)
                                                       ^
stringwrap.h:18:55: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
stringwrap.h: In function 'auto determineFirstPosition(std::__cxx11::string)':
stringwrap.h:35:21: error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'int' and then 'long long unsigned int'
     return s.length();
                     ^
stringwrap.cc: At global scope:
stringwrap.cc:7:27: error: 'length' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
 auto Stringwrap::length() const
                           ^~~~~
stringwrap.cc:7:27: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
stringwrap.cc:12:37: error: 'getFirstPosition' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
 auto Stringwrap::getFirstPosition() const
                                     ^~~~~
stringwrap.cc:12:37: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
```

---

When I use `auto` and compile `--std=c++14`, I get the following error:

```
C:\temp\v0.11>g++ -g -O2 -std=c++14 -Werror=conversion stringwrap.cc
In file included from stringwrap.cc:1:
stringwrap.h: In function 'auto determineFirstPosition(std::__cxx11::string)':
stringwrap.h:35:21: error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'int' and then 'long long unsigned int'
     return s.length();
                     ^
```

---

**Question:** How can I write portable C++11 code (Linux, Windows) that avoids type conversions in STL data types like `std::string` (as demonstrated above)?

Comment: C++11 doesn't support return type deduction, you need to use trailing return type `auto foo() -> std::string::size_type {...}`

Comment: just use `size_t`. Described problem is result of using 32 o 64 bit build type (system) .

Comment: @MarekR That isn't portable.  There is no requirement that `std::string::size_type` is `size_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is, in a sense. Since std::string size_type is`std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type`, and for standard allocator `size_type` would be `make_unsigned_t<difference_type>`, and the latter is `ptrdiff_t`, and that becomes `size_t` for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @NathanOliver *There is no requirement* Perhaps, but `size_t` should be no smaller than container size types, and is therefore safe to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` provides public types, like `std::string::size_type`, that you can use to define your function.  You can define your `determineFirstPosition` function like

```
inline std::string::size_type determineFirstPosition(const std::string s)
{
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (s.at(i))
        {
            case ' ':
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return s.length();
}
```

and if you don't want to repeat `std::string::size_type` all over the place you can add a using declaration to your class to shorten the name like

```
using pos_type = std::string::size_type;
```

and then you would just use `pos_type`.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) documentation, you can see the type is called

```
std::string::size_type
```

so just use that. You don't need to know or guess what primitive type it is a typedef *of* - you already have a useable name that is guaranteed to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) cannot use `auto` return type deduction.

For [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), reading your mind, you ported this:

```
inline unsigned long int determineFirstPosition(const std::string s)
{
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (s.at(i))
        {
            case ' ':
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return s.length();
}
```

to

```
inline auto determineFirstPosition(const std::string s)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (s.at(i))
        {
            case ' ':
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return s.length();
}
```

in this case your error was

```
    for (auto i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
```

because `auto i = 0` is an `int`, not the type of `s.length()`.

Do

```
    for (decltype(s.length()) i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
```

if you want to avoid naming types here.

Alternatively, you can use `std::string::size_type`.  Alternatively you can write an utility to let you `for(:)` over indexes into something;

```
template<class T> struct tag_t {using type=T;};

template<class X> using block_deduction = typename tag_t<X>::type;

template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class S>
struct indexer_t {
  S s;
  void operator++(){++s;}
  S operator*() const{ return s; }
  friend bool operator==( indexer_t const& lhs, indexer_t const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.s == rhs.s;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( indexer_t const& lhs, indexer_t const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.s != rhs.s;
  }
};
template<class S>
range_t<indexer_t<S>> indexes( block_deduction<S> start, S finish ) {
  return {{std::move(start)}, {std::move(finish)}};
}
template<class C>
auto indexes_into( C&& c ) {
  return indexes( 0, c.size() );
}
```

all of which lets you do:

```
for( auto i : indexs_into(s) )
```

instead of

```
for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cece58d3d9b3f12).

(as a side bonus,

```
template<class C>
auto iterators_into( C& c ) {
  return indexes( c.begin(), c.end() );
}
```

is also useful, allowing you to iterate over all valid iterators into a container without manually writing a `for(;;)` loop)

Comment: This is fascinating. I'm not going to use this (not right now, at least), but I will definitely study this method. There are some language features in here that are new to me.